# Extract strings in round brackets using regex in R

Tags: r, regex

In my transcripts, silent pauses are indicated in round brackets, e.g., (0.9) but also (.) for pauses < 0.3 seconds. I want to extract these pauses. However, transcribers' comments are indicated similarly, namely in double round brackets, e.g. ((coughs)).  For this example

```
yy <- c("well [yes right] (.)", "let's go ((giggles))", "oh [  we::ll] i do n't (0.5) know", "erm [°well right° ]", "(3.2)")
```

this extracts all the pauses but also the transcriber comment:

```
pattern <- "(\\(.*?\\))"
grep(pattern, yy, value=T) 
matches <- gregexpr(pattern, yy)
paus <- regmatches(yy, matches)
paus <- unlist(paus)
paus
[1] "(.)"        "((giggles)" "(0.5)"      "(3.2)"
```

To get rid of the comment, I tried this:

```
pattern <- "\\([^\\(].*?\\)[^\\)].*?"
```

That found "(0.5)" but failed to find the string-final pauses "(.)" and "(3.2)".
Any pointer?

Comment: `library(stringr); str_extract_all(yy, "\\(\\d+.\\d+\\)|\\(\\.\\)")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `str_extract` to extract the pattern which says an optional number followed by a decimal and then followed by another optional number value. We are using optional ("?") here to get the empty value "(.)".

```
library(stringr)
vec <- str_extract(yy, "(\\((\\d+)?(\\.(\\d)?\\)))")
vec
#[1] "(.)"   NA      "(0.5)" NA      "(3.2)"
```

and then use `is.na` to remove `NA` elements

```
vec[!is.na(vec)]
#[1] "(.)"   "(0.5)" "(3.2)"
```

---

Or using the same regular expression with base R `regmatches` saves a step to remove `NA` values.

```
regmatches(yy, regexpr("(\\((\\d+)?(\\.(\\d)?\\)))", yy))
#[1] "(.)"   "(0.5)" "(3.2)"
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option with `gsub`:

```
gsub("[^(]*(\\(([.0-9]+)\\)|\\b|\\B)[^)]*", "\\2", yy)
#[1] "."   ""    "0.5" ""    "3.2"
```

**Explanation of the pattern:**
. `[^(]*`: anything except an open bracket, 0 or more times
. `(\\(([.0-9]+)\\)|\\b|\\B)` : what we want to capture : an open bracket followed by a dot or digits, one or more times, followed by a closing bracket (we only want to capture the dot or digits part, hence `\\2` in the replacement part) or the empty string that can be at the edge of a word (`\\b`) or not (`\\B`). *N.B: Here we are not keeping the brackets around the pauses times but we could.*
. `[^)]*`: anything except a closing bracket, 0 or more times